# How can I generate a list of arguments unacceptable to getopts in Bash?

Tags: bash, getopts

Let's say I'm running `getopts` in a Bash script with the option string ":a:b" and I provide the following command line parameters:

```
./script.sh -a foo bar -b bar zappo
```

The instance of "foo" is an expected argument for the option `a` and the option `b` has no expected argument. However, both instances of "bar" and the instance of "zappo" are unacceptable to `getopts`. After running `getopts`, how can I echo a variable containing a list of all of the unacceptable arguments? How could I produce the list "bar bar zappo"? Thanks!

Here's some code for your convenience:

```
#!/bin.bash
option_string=":a:b"
unexpected_parameters=""
OPTIND=1
while getopts "${option_string}" options; do
    case ${options} in
        a)
            echo "-a triggered with parameter ${OPTARG}" >&2 # output to STDERR
            ;;
        b)
            echo "-b triggered" >&2 # output to STDERR
            ;;
        \?)
            echo "invalid option: -${OPTARG}" >&2 # output to STDERR
            ;;
    esac
    #<insert code magic... unexpected_parameters="${unexpected_parameters} "$(MAGIC)"">
done
echo "unexpected parameters: ${unexpected_parameters}"
```

Answer (score 1):

`getopts` stops processing at the first non-option argument. That's Posix-style argument processing. In Posix-style argument processing, given the command

```
utility -a foo bar -b bar zappo
```

`utility` will not interpret `-b` as a command-line flag. If `-a` takes an argument, then `bar` will be the first positional argument, and then there will be three more positional arguments, `-b`, `bar`, and `zappo`.

GNU extends this syntax by permuting command-line arguments so that flag options can be anywhere in the command-line. However, if you set the environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT`, then GNU utilities will (mostly) behave like normal Posix utilities. The GNU version of the Posix C library function `getopt(3)` (and `getopt_long(3)`) use GNU syntax by default, and also react appropriate to the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable.

However, the bash `getopts` builtin is strictly Posix-style. So in your case, with `getopts ":a:b"`, your loop will only be executed once, for flag `a` with argument `foo`. When `getopts` terminates, `OPTIND` is set the the index of the first unconsumed command-line argument, in this case `3` (`bar`).

If you want to use `getopts` with GNU-style option handling, you have to do the permuting yourself. For example, you could do something like this:

```
# Positional arguments are not necessarily unexpected; in fact, they are usually
# expected. So I accumulate them here in a bash array
positional=()
while (($#)); do
  # If you really wanted to do GNU style processing, you'd need to special case
  # '--' and "long options" starting with '--'. Here, I just do the simplest
  # thing, which is to pass anything that vaguely looks like an optional argument
  # (starts with a -) to getopts.
  if [[ $1 = -* ]]; then
    # Grab some options:
    while getopts "$option_string" option; do
      case $option in
        a) ... ;;
        # etc.
      esac
    done
    # get rid of whichever options we've handled and reset OPTIND
    shift $((OPTIND - 1))
    OPTIND = 1
  else
    # Accumulate and ditch the positional argument:
    positional+=("$1")
    shift
  fi
done
```

Alternatively, you can use the GNU implementation of `getopt(1)`, which will do all that for you, at the cost of a slightly more annoying interface. (At least, I find it annoying, but YMMV.)